# Pass multiple parameters in web API GET method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, get

I've the following piece of code to return a list of products based on category.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategoryId(string category_id)
        {
            return repository.GetAll().Where(
                p => string.Equals(p.Category, category_id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
```

I want to pass two parameters in the method, category and Brand.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategoryBrand(string category, string Brand)
        {
}
```

What would the return method look like with category and Brand?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategoryBrand(string category, string Brand)
{
    return repistory.GetAll().Where(
        p => string.Equals(p.Category, category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
        && string.Equals(p.Brand, brand, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

You just chain your conditions to the Where() using the && operator. If you want to match either brand or category, use ||